# How to send message to an address using solidity contract + truffle

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle

Here is the link to my code: https://github.com/nandinicbit1981/hello-truffle

The problem with this is: If I am sending a message: *Hello World*, I am getting the input field in the mined transaction as `@#$R%%%Hello World`.

I am not sure what is wrong with the code, I am new to ethereum. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ethereum Stack Exchange. Your post somehow ended up on meta, I moved it here. Also, it would be preferable if you could include essential parts of the code here, so people can help you to nail down the issue.